# Serialize unity3d C# objects to string and back

Tags: serialization, unity-game-engine, json.net, protobuf-net

Which one of the two is recommended approach given my server API is expecting a C# string? Which one will result in lowest string length?

1) Protobuf-net 
Using protobuf-net to convert object  <-> byte array 
Use Convert.ToBase64String methods for converting byte array <-> string

2) Use Json .Net directly to convert object <-> string

We have Protobuf-net working in our project with byte[] server APIs. Now our server is migrating to string APIs instead of byte[]. We are not sure whether we should move to Json .Net or stay with protobuf-net and use Convert Base 64 for extra string to byte[] conversion.

What do you suggest?

Comment: `Which one of the two is more performant given my server API is expecting a C# string` Simple. Read [this](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I wonder about the general merit of asking about benchmarking results... I would assume most cases to be covered by either 1. Tests that take < 1Hour to write or 2. Official benchmarks posted on the APIs website. In the case of an unperformed complex benchmark, well ... , then you're just gambling on someone else to either do it for you or having already done it in the not-so-distant past. Which, again, for some reason doesn't feel very helpful to this site.

Comment: @EZI Thank you for sharing the link. I totally agree with you. But if someone have already done the comparison or have been in the same boat. I prefer to learn from their experience instead of trying out myself.

Comment: @user3504386 Generally, in this scenario - since both frameworks will do approximately the same thing - I would favor the one that's less lines of code to write / reads better in the code.

In your case, I would (following my intuition) say that double converts are slower than single converts. However, json is more verbose than base64 strings of binary serialization, so you need to consider if bandwidth is your bottleneck or cpu ...

Comment: @NathanDortman unless the data is internally dominated by text contents, in which case json could be more efficient than (base-64)-of-(utf-8)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you Marc for sharing your expertise and great Protobuf-net asset..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is my thought process which I'm hoping can help you decide between the two:

Before deciding which one is better we need to have a better grasp of the context of the problem. Optimization is always something that has to be done under well defined "fitness" parameters. 
What I mean by this is:

- If you're most constrained by CPU usage, I would test to see which code uses more CPU to execute.
- If bandwidth is an issue, you'd want to look at the method that sends the smallest packets. (In which case base64 of binary serialization should be the answer.)
- If code readability is a factor, you should probably look at which code is easier to read / understand while taking less text to write. (In which case I suspect that the JSON route will have better readability)

In general, I would caution against over-optimization. Mainly because you might spend more time thinking and comparing than would be lost by your "unoptimized" code :)
That is to say, only optimize when you can clearly define your bottle-neck.

Hope this helped :)